# Add setTimeout to event listener

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble adding timeout to an event listener function.

`onclick` event does not seem to be an issue, but adding to function does not seem to be working.

Is jQuery required for this? I would like to add something like 3 or 5 seconds before the function is executed.

```
<HTML>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it". Wait 3 seconds, and the page will alert "Hello".</p>

<button id="btn">Try it</button>
<!--
onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);"
-->
<script>

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your script tag sits at least before the body tag

Comment: @AGE It was after the button before I converted to Stack Snippet.

Comment: @Barmar I understand, I think the issue is much more evident with the original source code as in this case, any modifications would serve to answer the question, which you did an excellent job with

Comment: The question is about `setTimeout`. My edit has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function that calls `setTimeout()`.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
});

function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}
```

```html
<p>Click "Try it". Wait 3 seconds, and the page will alert "Hello".</p>

<button id="btn">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barmar's answer, I would like to add a challenge and a tip:

Challenge - Now that your are capable of delayed alert, see what happens when the "Try it" button is tapped fast multiple times. Multiple alerts are shown. How can we make sure that only one alert is displayed at the end of every 3 seconds.

Tip - Having fast turn around time i.e. coding a feature and seeing that immediately on the screen is crucial when starting out. I used repl.it website in the past for that. You can try something like that or even have your own local setup although this might be little difficult to setup.